# создать вложенный JSON на JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Есть такая проблема, не могу создать вложенный JSON, есть два вложенных for'а которые должны создать JSON формата,

```
{
  index1 : {key1: val1, key2: val2},
  index2 : {key1: val1, key2: val2}
}
```

первый проход генерирует имя для index, второй проход создаёт key и val значения, как из этого правильно создать JSON.

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  

var tmp = {};
for ( var i=0; i < 10; i++ ){
 tmp['index' + i] = {};
 for ( var j=0; j < 15; j++ ){
       tmp['index' + i]['key' + j] = 'val' + j;
    }
}

console.log(tmp);
```

Comment: проблема в том что у меня весь JSON состоит из переменных . и если я пытаюсь собрать всё из переменных то выкидывает "typeerror cannot set property 0 of undefined"

Comment: ну напишите пример вашого кода, я же не могу знать все детали....

Comment: @vnn198 это не json

Comment: оказалось в одном месте была перменная в виде массива, теперь всё заработало